# laravel5 load js file after jquery-ui in non-base page

Tags: jquery, laravel-5

i want to use js file in non-base page,but when i add js file into my page,i have problem that it load above jquery-ui.js that i load in my layout base page,
i think i should assset manager but how can i? i want this:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="{{asset('/js/jquery-ui.js')}}"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="{{asset('/js/somejs.js')}}"></script>
```

but it load

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="{{asset('/js/somejs.js')}}"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="{{asset('/js/jquery-ui.js')}}"></script>
```

Comment: so reverse the order.. give us some php code help us to help you

Comment: you tagged laravel-5 which is php.. the code that is relevant to your problem.. if it blade let it be blade

Comment: my problem is not php code it is how load js after js in pages with laravel asset manager

Comment: laravel is php see:  "The PHP Framework For Web Artisans" https://laravel.com

Comment: I try to explain again how the script get where they are? like from where you include this js? why cant you just flip the order?

Comment: ok.do understand my problem?

Comment: yes, but to help you I need to see your code

Answer (score 0):

Just use this code to attached a script or stylesheet

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="{!! url('js/your-file.js') !!}"></script>
```

if your file inside public/js/your-file.js